# How open a .scala file inside a Jar

Tags: java, jar

I have a .scala file inside a JAR, how do i open from my code that isn't part of the jar?
For some additional precisions the jar file does not on classpath.

Here an example of my code. It works partially, the file on the jar is open but for that i create it from the folder "lib'.

Have you another idea for evitate the creation of the file on the folder?

Thanks !

```
protected Object openDialogBox(Control cellEditorWindow, Object value, String jarFileName)
        throws CoreException, IOException {

    IWorkspaceRoot myWorkspaceRoot = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
    IProject myProject = myWorkspaceRoot.getProject(ActiveProject.getNameProject());
    String fileProgramName = (String) value;
    InputStream stream;
    final boolean readOnly = (jarFileName != null);

    if (myProject.exists() && myProject.isOpen()) {  
        IFolder sourceFolder = myProject.getFolder( (jarFileName != null) ? "lib" : "src" );     
        if (sourceFolder.exists()) {

            final IFile programFile = sourceFolder.getFile(fileProgramName);
            if ( jarFileName != null ) {
                programFile.delete(true, new NullProgressMonitor());
                stream = JarUtil.getProgramFromJar(jarFileName, fileProgramName);                   
            } 
            else {       
                stream = createContentStream(myProject.getName(), programFile.getName().replace(".scala", ""));
            }
            if (!programFile.exists()) {
                // create the file
                programFile.create(stream, true, new NullProgressMonitor());    
            }
            programFile.refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_ZERO, null);
            stream.close(); 
            cellEditorWindow.getShell().getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {         
                     public void run() {            
                         IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
                                    .getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();            
                         try {
                             ResourceAttributes myAttributes = programFile.getResourceAttributes();

                             if (myAttributes == null) {
                                  myAttributes = new ResourceAttributes();
                             }
                             myAttributes.setReadOnly(readOnly);
                             try {
                                 programFile.setResourceAttributes(myAttributes);
                             } catch (CoreException e) {
                                 e.printStackTrace();
                             }
                             IDE.openEditor(page, programFile, true);
                         } catch (PartInitException e) {
                         }          
                     }          
            }); 
            return value;   

        }   
        return null;     
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: There is never a need to use `new String(String)`, just use `(String)value`. And you may shorten `(jarFileName != null) ? true : false` to just `(jarFileName != null)`

Comment: you may use `java.util.jar.JarFile` class if I understand you well

Comment: @GyroGearless you're right, but when code like that is better to understand by a programmer, it's ok to leave it

Comment: *Why* do you have a .scala file inside a JAR? JAR files are for object code and resources, not for source code.

Comment: @EJP actually a develop a gmf editor and then my node object need a property program that use a .scala file. The .scala file are inside of .jar